# TableView is not registering any events Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am attempting to create a list of items using the TableView widget in Corona. I followed their online examples and created the TableView. It appears on the screen and is scrollable, but no event is fired when I click a row, even though I set a listener for `OnRowTouch`.

```
local options_for_list_view = {
  id = "list_view",
  top = 0,
  left = 0,
  width = display.contentWidth,
  height = display.contentHeight,
  hideBackground = true,
  hideScrollBar = true,
  listener = on_table_touch,
  onRowRender = onRowRender,
  onRowTouch = on_row_touch, -- registering listener
}

list_view = widget.newTableView(options_for_list_view)

for key, value in pairs(trophy_list) do
  local params = 
  {
    name = key
  }

  list_view:insertRow
  {
    isCategory = false,
    rowHeight = total_height * 0.1,
    rowColor = rowColor,
    lineColor = { 0, 0, 0 },
    params = params
  }
end
```

Here is the listener:

```
local function on_row_touch( event )
  print("error")
end
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: Are You sure that `on_row_touch( event )` is defined before adding it to the `options_for_list_view`? Also, could You show `tableViewListener`, please? (`on_table_touch( event )`)

Comment: It was defined afterwards. I did not think that it would matter since they were in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define Your `on_row_touch( event )` function *BEFORE* adding it to the `options_for_list_view` Table.

Objects in Lua are created in the same order as listed in sources. So, in Your case, You're just putting a `nil` into the `onRowTouch` event's listener place. And just after that creating a local function which was supposed to be an event listener :)

Some proper static analysis tool should help getting rid of this kind of errors...

Good luck ;)

Simplified version:

```
print(foo())

function foo()
    return "some_value..."
end
```

Output:

`lua: ./call_test.lua:1: attempt to call global 'foo' (a nil value)`